# Adding buttons - side by side

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm using Tampermonkey on chrome to add a button to a web page. When clicked, the script analyzes the page, then shows an alert. This is the code the show the button:

```
 function Main(){
     GM_addStyle('.myButtonDiv {color: black; background-color: black}');
     var div = document.createElement('div');
     div.setAttribute('class', 'myButtonDiv');
     div.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="clickMe">';
     document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
     div.firstChild.addEventListener('click', runMyScript, true);
}
```

I have several of these scripts that may run on the same page. Right now the buttons are presented vertically, which takes up too much screen space.

How can I position them side by side in one row?

Thanks,
Nir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `display: inline-block` to CSS should help

```
GM_addStyle('.myButtonDiv {color: black; background-color: black; display: inline-block}');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline elements:

```
 GM_addStyle('.myButtonSpan {color: black; background-color: black}');
 var span = document.createElement('span');
 span.setAttribute('class', 'myButtonSpan');
 span.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="clickMe">';
 document.body.insertBefore(span, document.body.firstChild);
 span.firstChild.addEventListener('click', runMyScript, true);
```